# Angular Add-In for Outlook Access Token

Tags: angular, outlook-addin

I have followed the setup for creating an outook add-in with angular. But for some reason when I get the access token it looks strange. It doesn't have the scopes that I have setup (Send.Mail). This token doesn't look like a normal ID/Access Token (with the scp, user email, first name, last name, etc.)

[image]

I print out the token to the console by using this method:

```
  async getAzureAccessToken() {

    console.log('##########',)

    Office.context.mailbox.getCallbackTokenAsync({ isRest: true }, function (result: any) {
      console.log(result)
      if (result.status === "succeeded") {
        var accessToken = result.value;
        console.log(accessToken) 
      } else {
        console.log("Error getting the Azure access token: " + result.error);
      }
    });
  }
```